# Como hacer los input para tag (Keyword)

Tags: html, seo

Primera mente pido disculpa por pedir como hacer y no como solucionar.
He tratado de averiguar por toda Internet y no se si es que estoy buscando mal o es que no existe ningún tipo de información al respeto, pero tengo bastante tiempo queriendo hacer un input de Etiquetas o palabras claves así como el de YouTube.

Simplemente cuando colocas el texto y haces click en la tecla **enter** dentro del input se coloca la palabra por separada y puedes volver a escribir otra palabra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como logro hacer este input, por favor me seria de muchísima ayuda.
Un saludo

Comment: Puedes publicar tu código? Ya que asi es más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este plugin te puede ayudar [Tags Input](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/minimal-tags-input.html)

Forma basica de uso, recuerda que debes de importar a tu codigo los css y js:

```
<div class="myTags"></div>
<input type="text" class="inputTags" hidden />
<script>
$('.myTags').TagsInput({
  tagHiddenInput: $('.inputTags')
});
</script>
```

Mira la [documentación](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/minimal-tags-input.html) para más detalles del uso de ese plugin espero te sirva